# Add a DateTime Picker?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add a date time picker in HTML5 using MVC5 , as i created Datatype Date Time in Database.... So how to show Date Time picker??. I tried the following

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Jcss")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DeliveryDate").datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And in HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="DeliveryDate" id="DeliveryDate" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliveryDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: input type="date"?

Comment: @Amit already tried

Comment: do you see any errors in the console like "$ is not defined"? why is `jquery` reference added after `jquery-ui` and `jqueryval`? Try adding `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>` reference on top and try

Comment: @adiga had mention, jquery need to be load 1st b4 other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Answer to the question

Add this in header

```
  <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now scripts (Placing at foot):

```
 @section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input type="date" in HTML5 but it's not well supported. current version of Firefox doesn't support it so you likely to have a lot of trouble getting it worked.

I am using this plugin in my current project https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/